# Populate Text Fields on APEX Form using Array

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I am using a barcode scanner to scan in barcodes (that consist of the order^location - I use the ^ as a separator) which i then need to separate and put the two values into two text fields. The idea is to scan the barcode into a third text field and then its separated using a process after save is pressed - These are then saved into separate table columns. I have the below which separates the text but I am now trying to get the values held in the array into the text fields on the APEX form.

I have the below code which works in SQL developer with the following lines however when i changed them to try put the value into a text field it fails. I wondered whether i have it correct or maybe incorrect syntax?

```
 dbms_output.put_line(v_array(1)); -- This works in SQL Developer

 :P1_ORDER := dbms_output.put_line(v_array(1)); -- Fails in SQL Developer & APEX
```

I get the following when i attempt to run the below in SQL developer. Please can someone help me pass the values in my array to the text fields on my APEX Form. Thanks.

ORA-06550: line 17, column 13:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'PUT_LINE' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 17, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
 declare

  v_array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
  P1_ORDER number;
  P1_LOCATION number;

 begin

  -- Convert delimited string to array
  v_array := apex_util.string_to_table(:P1_JOB_NUMBER,'^');

  --dbms_output.put_line(v_array(1));
  --dbms_output.put_line(v_array(2));

  :P1_ORDER := dbms_output.put_line(v_array(1));
  :P1_LOCATION := dbms_output.put_line(v_array(2));

 end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See put_line is not a function ,its a procedure in dbms_output package .

You can't assign dbms_output.put_line to any variable .

Try this

```
declare

 v_array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
 P1_ORDER number;
 P1_LOCATION number;

begin

 -- Convert delimited string to array
 v_array := apex_util.string_to_table(:P1_JOB_NUMBER,'^');

 --dbms_output.put_line(v_array(1));
 --dbms_output.put_line(v_array(2));

 P1_ORDER := v_array(1);
 P1_LOCATION := v_array(2);

end;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works in SQL Developer however when i run the code on my APEX Form and it says "ORA-01403: no data found". I missed the colon on the text fields :p1_order and :p1_location, this made no difference. But we now the array works since its populating / working in sql developer